# "Romantic Harmony" example; Why does it work?

Tags: theory, harmony, tonal, romantic-period

I was reading some of Ted Greene's work and came across this PDF

http://www.tedgreene.com/images/lessons/chords/RomanticHarmony.pdf

In it, he goes from a vi6 chord (this 6 doesn't mean first inversion, it means the chord with an added major sixth, in this case spelled tonic-major sixth-minor third-fifth) to a I chord. I.e. from a Cm6 chord (spelled C-A-Eb-G) to Eb (spelled Bb-Bb-Eb-G).

I can't understand how this makes sense in the context of tonal harmony. Any help?

Comment: I don't know a lot about this, but one thing that is immediately clear is the major sixth of the vi6 chord is a leading tone to the fifth degree of the tonic. Another question is why that's not called a half diminished 7th chord instead.

Comment: Oh, a half diminished seventh has the diminished fifth and the minor seventh. There should be a name for the chord with a minor third, perfect fifth, and diminished seventh.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, by diminished seventh you mean minor 7th?

Comment: A major 7th is 11 half steps. A minor seventh is 10 half steps. A diminished 7th is 9 half steps. A minor 6th is 8 half steps. A major 6th is 9 half steps. So a diminished 7th and a major 6th are the same interval. A *half diminished 7th chord* is a minor third, diminished 5th, and minor 7th, like C Eb Gb Bb. A *fully diminished 7th chord* is a minor 3rd, a diminished 5th, and diminished 7th, like C Eb Gb Bbb.

Comment: In the key of Eb major, the I chord is Eb G B**b**, not B natural.

Comment: That's embarrasing, fixed. I think what you call a diminished seventh is what I call a major sixth, thus the chord you describe is the minor 6 chord (in jazz guitar parlance).

Comment: C to A is a major 6th, C to Bbb is a diminished 7th. The fact that Bbb and A are enharmonic means that the two intervals sound the same, and we should all be calling it one or the other name depending on the musical context, and not just using one name or the other all the time based on an arbitrary preference. Anyway, with the correction to Bb the leading tone idea is in play and I’m sure that is at least part of the “resolution” feel that these two chords have.

Comment: @ToddWilcox -- "There should be a name for the chord with a minor third, perfect fifth, and diminished seventh": parallel with _minor major seventh_ would be _minor diminished seventh_.

Comment: @DavidBowling - when you say 'parallel with' do you mean 'it's another way of saying'? R m3 P5 =minor. Never seen a d7, but plenty of m6, so on A - A C E F# = Am6.    mM7 would be A C E G#.

Comment: @Tim -- by "parallel with _minor major seventh_ I mean parallel in nomenclature. A minor major seventh chord specifies triad quality, followed by the name of the seventh interval. I was just pointing out that if you wanted to keep the diminished seventh interval you could call A-C-E-G♭ a _minor diminished seventh_, following the same rules of nomenclature. Agree, I have never seen this before either and would in practice call it an Am6.

Comment: @DavidBowling - reason I posted is that *minor major seventh* can't be the same as *minor diminished seventh*, as one has m7, the other d7, which gives a different note, not only in name, but sound. Agreed, the 'm6' could be 'md7', but not mM7.

Comment: @Tim -- right. Didn't intend to be confusing; parallel in the way the chords are named, but _mM7_ and _m6_ are not at all the same chords. This was only a comment to "There should be a name for...." of ToddWilcox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that he harmonized the 4th mode of Bb Major: the Eb lydian scale is a whole-tone tetrachord, a perfect fifth and a major tetrachord which gives us only two alterations Eb and Bb. In this case the vi chord would have a major 6th. Now i'm not sure vi6-I is a common modal cadence in Lydian (I would have thought II-I was) because the #IV degree (a half-diminished chord) is usually not used, nor is the raised fourth used as the fourth tone of a vi tetrad for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative analysis is to treat the tonic in your specific instance as a passing second-inversion to IV. e.g.

[image: Cmin added 6 - Eb 6/4 - Ab]